# How to create the same random numbers on different computers with Armadillo?

Tags: c++, random, armadillo, prng

I am using the Armadillo c++ library, that allows high-perfomance computation of matrices and vectors. This library has built-in functions to populate its objects with random numbers. I use it in the context of a procedurial random generation of an object. The object creation is random, but no matter how often I recreate the object, it remains the same as long as the seed remains the same.

The issue is that, although I can set the seed to a determined value, and thus recreate the same run on my machine... I lose the coherence of the randomness when going to a different computer. I come from the enchanted land of Matlab where I can specify the function used for the generation of pseudo-random numbers. So, this generation can be cross platform if one chooses the function well. **But how do I specify the RNG function for Armadillo?**

My research has led me to this source documentation, that "detail" the process of random number generation:

http://arma.sourceforge.net/internal_docs_4300/a01181_source.html
http://arma.sourceforge.net/internal_docs_4300/a00087.html

But i have no clue on what to do here: this code is much more advanced than what I can write. I would appreciate any help!

Thank you guys!

Remarks:
- I do not care how good the random function used is. I just want a fast cross-platform cross-architecture generator. Deterministic randomness is my goal anyway.
- In details, in case it matters, the machines to consider should be intel processors, windows or mac, 32b or 64b.
- I have read the several posts mentionning the use of seeds for randomness but it seems that the problem here is the cross-platform context and the fact that the random generator is buried (to my untrained eyes at least) within Armadillo's code.

Comment: A quick glance at the API and it seems unclear why using the same seed on a different machine yields different results. Maybe it's just a bug! As the library is open source, you could try debugging it.

Comment: Implementations of std::rand() will differ across operating systems (and operating system versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++98 / C++03 mode, Armadillo will internally use std::rand() for generating random numbers (there's more to it, but that's a good approximation of what's happening).

If you move from one operating system to the next (or across two versions of the same operating system), there is no guarantee that the system provided random number generator will be the same.

If you use Armadillo in C++11 mode, you can use any random number generator you like, with the help of the [.imbue()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#imbue) function. Example:

```
std::mt19937 engine;  // Mersenne twister random number engine with default parameters

std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distr(0.0, 1.0);

mat A(123,456);

A.imbue( [&]() { return distr(engine); } );  // fill with random numbers provided by the engine
```

The [Mersenne twister](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) random number engine is provided as standard functionality in C++11. The default parameters should be stable across compiler vendors and versions, and are independent of the operating system.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. I didn't know or use the imbue function -- and I should admit I do not understand what each symbol of the last line means (especially "[&]" ?!) but I can use it alright! A side question then: why is it not possible to override the std::rand() generator to create numbers differently then? I understand std::rand() is probably very well written and a very good function, but as I say i'm more focused on reproductibility rather than performance at this point.